# Asp.NET MVC Inserting data into mssql database gives table object error

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

when a user register i want to insert some extra data into a other table AspNetUserStatics. But when the user register i got this error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The request for procedure 'AspNetUserStatics' failed because 'AspNetUserStatics' is a table object.

I tried multiple ways to add code data into my database with other stack overflow posts. But i can't find the solution. Maybe it is a simple stupid thing that wil solve this but i am new and need to learn things. So it will great if someone can help me.

```
                    connection();

                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("AspNetUserStatics", con);
                    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", user.Id);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Points", 5);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Day", DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PointsNewUser", 1);

                    con.Open();
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Here is the the full code: https://pastr.io/view/iPeGBL

Error: The request for procedure 'AspNetUserStatics' failed because 'AspNetUserStatics' is a table object.

Full Error Page: https://pastr.io/view/I59Q2a

I want all the data will be insert into the table AspNetUserStatics.

Regards,
Bart

Comment: The error is self-explanatory.  You are trying to execute a table as a stored procedure.  You need to use an INSERT statement instead of trying to run / execute the table.

Comment: Either create a procedure to insert your data or use an insert statement. You can't execute a table.

Answer (score 0):

For what I can see you are trying to send data to a stroed procedure, but "AspNetUserStatics" is a table. you should use an insert statement instead, something like

```
insert into AspNetUserStatics (Id, points, ....) values (@Id, @Points,....)
```

Comment: Ok i understand, I will try this way and let you know if it works.
Thank you

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks for helping me. i love to learn coding in asp.net and C# and its always nice that this community is here to help people!

Comment: Glad it helped :)